# How to run Diskpart from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-11, vhdx

My system: **Windows 11 64 bit with all updates** to date.

I have a VHD on my hard drive. If i go into `Disk Management` i can click **Action > Attach > Select File** and i see a mapped drive.

I now turn to a cmd prompt and run the following:

```
diskpart
```

**{Press enter}** and type

```
select vdisk file="C:\Virtual Drives\MyVhd.vhdx"
```

this too does the same thing but using a cmd prompt.

I am attempting to attach this drive at startup (so will eventually create a `Scheduled Task`) but if i execute the command in one row

```
diskpart select vdisk file="C:\Virtual Drives\MyVhd.vhdx"
```

under the directory c:\Windows\System32 or c:\Windows\System from a cmd prompt it doesnt map/attach the drive.

I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart but it doesnt clarify how i can move the command line to `DiskPart` or how i can run it from the command line?

Comment: To create a diskpart script, create a text file that contains the Diskpart commands that you want to run, with one command per line, and no empty lines. You can start a line with rem to make the line a comment. To use: `diskpart /s scriptname.txt`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart-scripts-and-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier by using the PowerShell command
[Mount-VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/mount-vhd?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

Example command :

```
Mount-VHD -Path c:\test\testvhdx.vhdx
```

If you intend running this command from a `.bat` file, use this:

```
powershell "Mount-VHD -Path c:\test\testvhdx.vhdx"
```